# Why is Collatz Conjecture Program Not Working for Large Integers in Java

Tags: java, math, integer-overflow, collatz

This is a program I made to simulate the Collatz Conjecture on Java:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Collatz {
public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner raj= new Scanner(System.in);
    int n;
    int k=0;
    System.out.print("n? ");
    n = raj.nextInt();
    while(n > 1){
        if(n%2 ==1){
            n=3*n+1;
            System.out.println(n);
            k++;
        }
        if(n%2==0){
            n=n/2;
            System.out.println(n);
            k++;
        }

    }
    System.out.print("It took " + k + " iterations!");
}

}
```

When I put in n=6, I get

> 3
>      10
>      5
>       16
>       8
>       4
>       2
>       1
>       It took 8 iterations!

But when I put, say, n= 63728127, I get

> 191184382
>   95592191
>   286776574
>   143388287
>   430164862
>   215082431
>   645247294
>   322623647
>   967870942
>   483935471
>   1451806414
>   725903207
>   -2117257674
>   -1058628837
>   It took 14 iterations!

What went wrong? Why? How can I fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a classic case of integer overflow. Primitive ints have a limited range in Java. The solution is to always use something like [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) if you have to deal with large integers.

Incidentally, things would be so much easier if Java supported operator overloading like almost all other modern languages.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.math.BigInteger;


public class Collatz {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner raj= new Scanner(System.in);
        int k=0;
        System.out.print("n? ");

        BigInteger n = BigInteger.valueOf(raj.nextLong());

        while(n.compareTo(BigInteger.ONE) > 0){
            if(n.testBit(0)){
                n = n.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(3));
                n = n.add(BigInteger.ONE);
                System.out.println(n);
                k++;
            }
            else {
                n = n.divide(BigInteger.valueOf(2));
                System.out.println(n);
                k++;
            }
        }
        System.out.print("It took " + k + " iterations!");
    }
}
```

Comment: So then how would I edit the program to use this BigInteger class? I dont understand how to implement it